# Function returning number of subsets of size $k$ of a set of size $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, special-functions, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for a function that returns the number of subsets of size $k$ of a set of size $n$. Ideally, the function is commonly used.

I took a look at the binomial coefficient. However, there seems to be a problem if $k$ is greater than $n$. For example, if $k = 2$ and $n = 1$, then we consider the number of two-element subsets of a singleton. In the example, the function that I am looking for should return $0$ and the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ seems to be undefined.

P.S.:
I used the following definition for the binomial coefficient (see the tag info page for binomial-coefficients):
$\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Comment: It is a common convention to let $\binom n k = 0$ for $k<0$ or $k>n$.

Comment: In the case you want, it is defined, and it is zero. Use the definition $${n\choose k}={n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)\over k!}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It's not really a definition. And it's simpler than that -- how many subsets of size 7 are there in a set of size 4?

Comment: Actually, it's kind of hard to understand what you're really asking. The function you're looking for is defined precisely by your own description. Are you looking for a convenient formula for this function, or its commonly used name, or notation, or effective ways to compute it?

Comment: @nik, you and I and OP all know there are zero size 7 subsets of a set of size 4, but OP wants a function that will return zero on that input, and OP is of the opinion that $n\choose k$ won't do it. My point is that if you define $n\choose k$ right --- if you *don't* define it as $n!/(k!(n-k)!)$ --- then it does what OP wants.

Comment: You could also just use $\Gamma(n+1)$ in place of $n!$. The poles of the gamma function will cause every "bad" coefficient to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the binomial coefficient works in this case since for $k>n$ we have one factor in the numerator which equals zero:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots\overbrace{(n-n)}^{=0}\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=0$$